# Python, openpyxl: I get the wrong value when running get_highest_column()

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am practicing with openpyxl and I'm working on an Excel file called 'test.xlsx'. The file only has 3 columns and 7 rows. The .xlsx file was created with LibreOffice.

When I run...

```
>>> #! python3 
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
>>> sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
>>> sheet.get_highest_column()
1025
```

The returned value should be 3.

A quick Google search suggested I run:

```
>>> sheet.calculate_dimension()
```

and got the return value:

```
'A1:AMK7'
```

This should only be `'A1:C7'`.

I remember reading that LibreOffice could be part of the problem to this.
However, I can't switch to MSOffice, and I hate OpenOffice.

Is there suggestion on how I could fix this, or work around it?
Thanks!

Comment: Another solution is `rango=wb.max_column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using older versions of LibreOffice and openpyxl. LibreOffice did used to set a default value of "A1:AMK7" for the dimensions but it version 5 doesn't seem to be doing that any more. openpyxl used to rely on the dimensions tag when reading files but hasn't done this for a while. Please try using openpyxl 2.3-b2

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input! I updated LibreOffice to 5 and openpyxl to v 2.3-b2. Problem solved. Thanks!